android cuttlefish aosp-android14-gsi virtual device booting error on raspberry pi 4b
I'm using android cuttlefish v1.0.0 docker image
docker-image-arm64 on raspberry pi 4b 4gb ram + raspberry pi os lite 64bit
$ cat /etc/rpi-issue
Raspberry Pi reference 2024-07-04
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen, 48efb5fc5485fafdc9de8ad481eb5c09e1182656, stage2

$ cat /etc/debian_version
12.8

$ uname -a
Linux hostname 6.6.62+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.62-1+rpt1 (2024-11-25) aarch64 GNU/Linux

I succeeded boot up aosp-android12-gsi virtual device and aosp-android13-gsi virtual device.
but, can't boot up aosp-android14-gsi
virtual device.
i think following message is the reason but don't know how to solve it.
crosvm E 12-12 05:31:19 25153 25153 :769] exiting with error 1: failed to connect to vhost-user socket path /tmp/cf_avd_0/cvd-1/internal/vhost_user_mac80211
Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)
$ ls -lZ /tmp/cf_avd_0/cvd-1/internal/vhost_user_mac80211
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root ? 0 Dec 12 05:31 /tmp/cf_avd_0/cvd-1/internal/vhost_user_mac80211

logcat is empty.
launcher output
kernel log
launcher log


it is similar when it comes to aosp-main-throttled
booting is freezed after following message.
The following lines contain useful debugging information:
  Point your browser to https://localhost:8443 to interact with the device.
  Serial console is disabled; use -console=true to enable it.
  Logcat output: /cf/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/logs/logcat
  Kernel log: /cf/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/kernel.log
  Launcher log: /cf/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/logs/launcher.log
  Instance configuration: /cf/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/cuttlefish_config.json
  Launcher Build ID: 12788822

launcher log
